# Guide to upgrade javascript application

Tags: javascript, upgrade

I am currently working on an application that uses multiple javascript libraries.
 In an attempt to upgrade our system I want to upadte all these js libraries. 
I searched online for a guide that helps me do this in a standard way but I couldn't find anything. 
Does anyone here know a useful resource?

Comment: Normally good libraries will document the upgrade steps on their website or GitHub repositories, along with the release notes/version history. So you should refer to them first of all. If you have difficulties with any specific portion of the code, you can post a minimal example demonstrating the problem with a particular version change, and we can help with it.

Comment: If the browser requests the libraries one by one and their names do not have version numbers, the put all scripts in a directory under your app that has a version number:  /v12345/scripts/jquery.js, /v12345/scripts/otherlib.js

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-size-fits-all solution.

Notice the version difference. Version 1.2.3 = major.minor.bugfix. Major upgrade usually means there are breaking changes that might break your code. Have a look at that library's version release note.

For example, if you included library XYZ version **1**.2.3 and you want to upgrade it to latest version **4**.5.6, you'll probably have broken system. If you're upgrading to **1**.8.2, you're safe to upgrade. That's if that library developer(s) follows the [semantic versioning guideline](https://semver.org/).

**Quick solution (not recommended + dangerous):** upgrade all, do a quick test, if everything seems fine, you're good to go.

**Proper solution:** upgrade 1 library at a time, test all functions where it's been used. repeat.